# How can I interact with a kernel(linux kernel)?

Tags: java, linux-kernel, kernel

What i am trying to do is an app similar to teamviewer using java.I was thinking to get the Input stream (monitor's) and send it to client so that the other machine can show the screen. I learnt that kernel acts as an interface between hardware and software, and i end up asking about kernel's interaction. can u plz give me the idea so that i can get things done..
Am i doing things wrong??
Please help me out..

Comment: My head is going to implode. Anyway, timers are used to "give instructions" to a processor at a specific time. Where "give instructions" implies "run some code" weather it is C or Java, eg. Java already has support for timers ..

Comment: I'm sorry, but this Question makes no sense to me.  Please try to explain clearly, and in more detail what you are trying to do.  "Give instructions directly to a processor" means nothing to me, and I cannot see any connection with what you *might be* asking and the OS kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ScheduledExecutorService to perform an action or task after a specific delay (or at a specific time).

This is how you can trigger a thread and therefor the processor to perform instructions at a given time.

> I was thinking to get the Input stream (monitor's) and send it to client so that the other machine can show the screen.

For this sort of question is it not to useful to think in terms of what the kernel is actually doing other than to not you can't pass an InputStream from one process to another, let alone one machine to another.

What you can do if establish a socket connection between the two machines and copy the InputStream into the Socket connection.  At the other end you will get an InputStream which has all the data the original InputStream has.

> I learnt that kernel acts as an interface between hardware and software, and i end up asking about kernel's interaction.

The kernel's role is to control and manage the TCP socket and the network adapter. The JVM interacts with the kernel for you so you don't need to know all the details, in fact you don't need to know the actual system call used which is useful as it can be different on different OSes.

Comment: i appreciate ur answer sir.I think i was not specific.What i am trying to do is an app similar to teamviewer using java.I was thinking to get the Input stream (monitor's) and send it to client so that the other machine can show the screen. I learnt that kernel acts as an interface between hardware and software, and i end up asking about kernel's interaction. can u plz give me the idea so that i can get things done. –

Comment: @user3111561 I have extended my answer based on your additional questions.